# Expire any checkout session before creating a new one in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

In my application, I am using stripe subscription and before I redirect the user to the stripe checkout session I create a `tempObject` which includes some data of how the money is divided throughout our application so When a user completes the subscription I then use this `tempObject` to create `subscriptionObject` which basically includes the subscription id and some other data similar to tempObject. Now I am using checkout_sessions and because of that i have to redirect the user to the session and there they can enter card details to complete the payment and for that reason, I am caching data in tempObject and all

Now the problem is that the user is able to create 2 checkout sessions in different tabs. Basically, user can open 2 tabs or more and then create checkout_session with different prices and because of that my model gets confused essentially allowing the user to create a subscription for more than the user actually paid for

The solution should be that before creating a new session the application should expire any previous sessions which are life. So i need to know how that might be possible

Comment: It would be helpful if you included your code.

Comment: There is no need for code. I just want to know that if user tries to create a new session then it should check and expire any other session first only then it will create a new session that way there will only be one session live everytime.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API for expiring checkout sessions, you can find it here:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/expire

Comment: I am familiar with this but how would i check that a session is live using customer_id? So the flow should be that user click on checkout and it should check if there is any session live if so then expire those and create a new one. So there will only be one session everytime

Comment: There is an endpoint, three below the one linked above, that is used to [list all Checkout Sessions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list). You can use that, passing the Customer's ID to the `customer` parameter to filter results for a specific Customer, to get a list of Checkout Sessions. You can then step through those results and cancel any that haven't already been cancelled.